# Combine pop() and setdefault() in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a method where if an item is not in a dictionary then it uses the last member of a list and updates the dictionary accordingly.  Sort of like a combination of the pop and setdefault method.  What I tried was the following:

```
dict1 = {1:2,3:4,5:6}
b = 7
c = [8,9,10]
e = dict1.setdefault(b, {}).update(pop(c))
```

So I would like the output to be where `{7:10}` gets updated to dict1, that is to say, if b is not in the keys of dict1 then the code updates dict1 with an item using b and the last item of c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be possible for you to abuse a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = [8, 9, 10]
dict1 = defaultdict(c.pop, {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6})
b = 7
e = dict1[b]
```

This will pop an item from `c` and make it a value of `dict1` *whenever a key missing from `dict1` is accessed*. (That means the expression `dict1[b]` on its own has side-effects.) There are many situations where that behaviour is more confusing than helpful, though, in which case you can opt for explicitness:

```
if b in dict1:
    e = dict1[b]
else:
    e = dict1[b] = c.pop()
```

which can of course be wrapped up in a function:

```
def get_or_pop(mapping, key, source):
    if key in mapping:
        v = mapping[key]
    else:
        v = mapping[key] = source.pop()

    return v

⋮
e = get_or_pop(dict1, b, c)
```

Comment: `defaultdict(c.pop, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your variables, you could use the following code snippet

```
dict1[b] = dict1.pop(b, c.pop())
```

where you are updating the dictionary "dict1" with the key "b" and the value c.pop(), (last value of the list in c, equivalent to c[-1] in this case). Note that this is possible because the key value b=7 is not in you original dictionary.